# Bash: array iteration and check not returning

Tags: arrays, bash, function, iteration

I want to create a bash function that iterates over an array and returns `0` if an element passed as argument does not exist in the array, or `1` otherwise.

The following code however does not print anything on `stdout`.

```
function checkparsed {
  tocheck="$1"
  shift
  for item in $@
    do
      if [ "$item" = "$tocheck" ]; then
        return 0
      fi
  done
  return 1
}

mdfiles=('foo')
echo "$(checkparsed foo ${mdfiles[@]})"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are capturing the *output* of the function (there is none).

To print `0` or `1`, either `echo` them in the function directly (don't forget to `return`), or use `echo $?` after running the function.

To handle spaces and glob characters in elements in `${mdfiles[@]}`, you should use double quotes:

```
for item in "$@"
# and
checkparsed foo "${mdfiles[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the issue:

```
echo "$(checkparsed foo ${mdfiles[@]})"
```

since your function is not echoing anything but you are returning values `0` or `1`.

You actually need to check for `$?` for the return value from your function:

```
checkparsed foo ${mdfiles[@]}
echo $?

0
```

Or else use return value in condition evaluation:

```
checkparsed foo ${mdfiles[@]} && echo "found" || echo "not found"
found

checkparsed food ${mdfiles[@]} && echo "found" || echo "not found"
not found
```